# How to delay a JavaScript file to load last in C# using HtmlTextWritter

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint-2007

I have a web part that I have created that displays some analog clocks in conjuction with whatever time zone a user specifies.  The problem that I am having is that my clocks will sometimes load and sometimes not.  I believe that my problem lies in the loading order of my js files.  I have the js loading in a OnLoad event in my web part code, and my clock.js file(the file that builds the clocks) is getting run first before my code that give the UTC time + the offset is difined.

Here is my code to display the clocks the clocks:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
    base.Render(output);


var skins = this._ClockSkins.ToString();

output.Write("<table align=\"center\"><tr>");

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{



output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Script);
output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/javascript");

//output.Write("var time;");
output.Write("function LoadTrigger() {");
output.Write("document.write('<span><div width=\"90px\"><td width=\"90px\" valign=\"top\" align=\"center\" ><canvas class=\"CoolClock:" + skins + "\" id=\"[" + i + "]\" ></canvas></td></div></span>');");
output.Write("}");
output.Write("window.onload = LoadTrigger();");
//output.Write("window.setTimeout(\"LoadTrigger()\", 1000);");
output.RenderEndTag();

//output.Write("<script defer=\"defer\" type=\"text/javascript\">document.write     ('<span><div width=\"90px\"><td width=\"90px\" valign=\"top\" align=\"center\" ><canvas class=\"CoolClock:" + skins + "\" id=\"[" + i + "]\" ></canvas></td></div></span>');</script>");
}

output.Write("</tr></table>");


}
}
```

Now sometimes the clocks will render fine, and sometimes I will have the shell for my analog clocks and no minute or second hands(those are rendered based off of what time zone it is set for).  As you can see from my commented out code, I have tried several different ways of getting this to work right.  Any sugestions on why my clocks work sometimes and if I refresh the page a few times they will work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='clock.js'></script>
");
}, 1000);
```

to delay the writing of this inclusion in your page.

Comment: I have tried that and the problem that I face is that this is a wsp. JavaScript files cannot be called from the scr="myjs.js method because they are not sitting on the root level of the project, and they are not in the 12 hive, so no "_layouts/myjs.js either". I have loaded them into the assembly, and since SharePoint is an evil moster sometimes, this is how it has to be done.   I have tried timeouts all over the place too.  I am beginning to think that it is just not going to work. :)  Thanks for your help much appreciated.

Comment: Yea, I thought that was too simple for you to not have already tried. I suppose if you wanted to get messy, you could write the contents of the .js file out to the page.

Comment: I would, but it is a large file :)  What makes me mad is the webservice call that I am using is in JavaScript and I think that is where my problem lies.  I was using a C# webservice call that worked great; however, I am having to deploy this to multiple environments and that means hard coding the url for the webservice  in the web.config.  With the JS I do not have to do that(window.href) but I cannot get this thing to render every time.  The wierd thing is that it will work, but only when it wants to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling a js file, are you able to actually use JQuery?  If you were able to add JQuery into the .js file you could then use this:

$(document).ready(function(){
...your stuff here...
});

Which would then execute once the page was loaded.

Comment: I can, but if you look at the code, my JavaScript that I use is inside of the C# HtmlTextWriter method. This meeans that it is still not going to hit the $(document).ready(function {....}); until everything that I need has run.  Trust me, I have gone through all of the obvious.  Like I said, I think that I am going to have to just use the C# webservice call and manually go in and change the URL in the web.config file.  Again, it is not that my code is not working at all, it just will not load everytime the page is loaded or refreshed.  But it will load when SharePoint feels like doing it :)

Comment: Understood. What I was trying to suggest is remove the line: output.Write("window.onload = LoadTrigger();");  and instead add something like: output.Write("$(document).ready(function(){LoadTrigger();});"); which would then allow you to create the function in the HtmlTextWriter method but have it trigger via the JQuery that validates the page is completely loaded.

Comment: You would still need to be sure that the JQuery library was loaded and you could add that in either the master page, a content editor on the same page that has the webpart or with a similar line in your HtmlTextWriter like: output.Write("<script Type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='...path to a library with js code/jquery-1.4.2-min.js></script>");");  or something similar.  Just trying to banter some ideas.

Comment: I will give that a try.  I do not think that I have tried the way you are suggesting yet.  Loading the library in the HtmlTextWriter I have tried and it still did not function correctly.  I will try the $(document).ready(function(){LoadTrigger});  Thank you very much for your ideas.

Comment: I tried that way and the SharePoint page did not like it.  The page would not load anything.  This thing is pissing me off.  I redeployed the web part and it worked great for about 15 refreshes, then it decides not to work again.  Refreshed then it worked again. uuuugggghhhhhh!!!!  I am sure in the normal way of working with js and C# everything would work fine.  Sharepoint just has to make things difficult.